# How to close all layers in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I want to close all layers in Mapinfo except one and again add one layer. How to do so in Mapinfo using Mapbasic or without?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will close all layers except one using a layer name to check what to keep open:

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim tables as Integer
Dim tableName as String

tables = NumTables()

For i = 0 To tables
    tableName = TableInfo(i,TAB_INFO_NAME)
    '' Check to see if the table is anything but the one we are looking for.
    If Not tableName = "{Your table name to check here}" Then
        Close Table tableName 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I would like to ask is hiding layer valid way to to change the selection of any query when I am hiding data from master table and only displaying result using query?

Comment: closing table closes layer but I would like to hide "Display Off" layer and how to get available layers above code would give error  if table is present and layer is not added