# What kind of table is bingHybrid?

Tags: cartography, mapinfo, mapbasic

I closed all table but I don't wan't to close underlying map eg like bingHybrid in mapinfo. How to prevent. Any detail about there map and way to handle while closing layers would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this more info for http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11764/how-to-close-all-layers-in-mapinfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tableinfo() with TAB_INFO_NAME or TAB_INFO_TYPE as argument to test for before you close a table.